# Заргузка ЦП драйвером, Windows

Tags: cpu

Здравствуйте коллеги! Есть проблема с загрузкой процессора в Windows.

Дело обстоит так: у меня есть драйвер (написан на Си) и программа-подписчик драйвера (написана на С++).

Когда я запускаю драйвер, а потом программу все работает верно: Диспетчер показывает загрузку ЦП на 80-95% (это нормальный результат, т.к. создается соответствующая нагрузка) и комп работает нормально. Но после 30 (примерно) минут работы показатель загруженности ЦП в Диспетчере падает до 40-50% и комп начинает жутко глючить и тормозить.

Драйвер работает постоянно и сам по себе систему вообще не грузит, но когда запускаю подписчика, начинаются торможения, которые не прекращаются даже после завершения работы программы.

Я так понимаю, что проблема в драйвере, а вернее в общении драйвера с программой-подписчиком со стороны драйвера (на сколько знаю, ресурсы, что используются драйверами не отображаются в Диспетчере, но ресурсы они используют, безусловно) но не могу найти баг. Подскажите пожалуйста (какие-то инструменты / программы / методы, хоть что-то)

1. Как я могу точно определить в чем действительно проблема, потому что она может быть не в драйвере или не только в драйвере (я не уверен)?.
2. Если проблема с драйвером, как я могу отловить проблемный участок кода?
   Большое спасибо!

Comment: Утечка памяти, растёт потребление памяти, либо остаются нужные обрывки данных и большая работа со свопом.

Comment: я бы начал с этого https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier